# PHP / MySQL character encoding incompatible?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm having what I believe to be an encoding issue with a 
mysql connection from php, print shows the query fine, 
and if I run the printed query on phpmyadmin, it returns 
results, but comes back empty from my script, does anyone 
know where can I look to figure out what's going on?

this is the offending query:

```
SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name_es = 'Pédagogie / Enseignement' OR name_fr = 'Pédagogie / Enseignement'
```

the same query with different values for the WHERE clause (values without é or other non-english characters) work fine, that's why I think it's encoding-related.

Retrieving and printing these data from the database is working just fine

Thanks

[EDIT: I think the problem might be that I'm grabbing the text that I'm querying from an uploaded file as writing the exact same text into a search text input I have which generates the exact same query works fine]

[RESOLVED: This was apparently caused by a space character encoded weirdly. It printed fine, but a double-encoded print showed difference between the queries I talk about in the [edit]]

Comment: did you try using the \u escape sequence for Unicode characters? Else, url encode the name, and decode it when retrieving it.

Comment: I'm looking for that, and can't find it. Is it php or mysql side?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but you could try this (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), and decode when you retrieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently caused by differently encoded whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to see if it works. Also check 'MySQL connection collation' in phpMyAdmin for your database.

Comment: hm, maybe not. Specially the form. I'll check now